# How to enable filesystem.h or fix experimental/filesystem?

Tags: c++, c++17, clion

I must write code for filesystem for my project. I am using Linux and Clion for my work. I am include and try to compile simple code for  but there is error which said there is no reference to std::experimental::filesystem::create:directories. Compiler is c++ by default(I tried gcc but there is errors too). I can't include only  and I dont have idea what to do next. Can anyone help me?

I expect created directory via std::experimental::filesystem::create_directory("root)

Comment: With gcc try the compiler option   -lstdc++fs

Comment: @Vlad that is a linker option, not a compiler option.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your compiler, its standard library and its versions you need to link with the separate filesystem library:

- GCC from 6.x and 7.x: `#include <experimental/filesystem>` gives you `std::experimental::filesystem` and you must then link with `-lstdc++fs`
- GCC 8.x and newer: `#include <filesystem>` gives you `std::filesystem` and you must then link with `-lstdc++fs`
- Clang/libc++ 5.x to 6.x: `#include <experimental/filesystem>` gives you `std::experimental::filesystem` and you must then link with `-lc++experimental`.
- Clang/libc++ 7.x and newer: `#include <filesystem>` gives you `std::filesystem` and you must then link with `-lc++fs`.

Note you'll need libc++ built explicitly with

```
-DLIBCXX_INSTALL_EXPERIMENTAL_LIBRARY=YES
```

and/or

```
-DLIBCXX_INSTALL_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY=YES
```

Comment: I have GCC 8.3.4 but there is no filesystem.h,only experimental/filesystem

Comment: @Bačić That's odd, because e.g. the Debian package has it: https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/libstdc++-8-dev/filelist.

Comment: I have files in this path(usr/include/c++/8...) but in Jetbrains Clion and other editors, I cant include filesystem library. Should I install something for that?

Comment: @Bačić I'm sorry, I can't help you with CLion as i have never used it before. Are you sure you are using GCC 8 and not some other compiler version?

Comment: I use GCC by default in Code Blocks and in Clion. Problem exist in Code Blocks too. When I type gcc --v in terminal I got 8.3.0 version of gcc. Clion auto-detect c++ compiler but problem is same with any of them.

Comment: Have you enabled C++17 through `-std=c++17` or in CMake doing `set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)`?

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem. For all who reading this question, in CMakeLists.txt you must link libraries BEFORE everything else. CMakeLists.txt must be like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(FileSystem)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
link_libraries(-lstdc++fs)
add_executable(FileSystem main.cpp Superblok.cpp Superblok.h Inode.cpp Inode.h 
Memory.cpp Memory.h Filesystem.cpp Filesystem.h)
```

if you put `link_libraries(-lstdc++fs)` in the end,your code wont work.